# Apache Nifi ListFTP "Connection Refused"

Tags: apache-nifi

### Can't connect to network drive

I have a instance of NiFi installed on Linux running Windows virtually.  I am trying to use the ListFTP and FetchFTP processors to watch and pull files from a network shared drive with separate log in credentials from the user login for the VM instance.  All of my attempts to connect to the network drive have failed so far with the same error (also visible in full log file below):

```
ListFTP[id=017010c5-a979-1da8-6ea7-d19acc59a3e7] Failed to perform listing on remote host due to Connection refused: connect: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have tried to connect to the XXX.YYY.com hostname as well as ping the IP address and use that as a hostname.  I can connect to the drive within the Windows instance with the same username and password credentials I am using in NiFi.

---

#### log file

```
2020-03-31 10:18:19,937 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ListFTP ListFTP[id=017010c5-a979-1da8-6ea7-d19acc59a3e7] Failed to perform listing on remote host due to Connection refused: connect: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:243)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:181)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.FTPTransfer.getClient(FTPTransfer.java:592)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.FTPTransfer.getListing(FTPTransfer.java:229)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.FTPTransfer.getListing(FTPTransfer.java:192)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFileTransfer.performListing(ListFileTransfer.java:106)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.list.AbstractListProcessor.listByTrackingTimestamps(AbstractListProcessor.java:472)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.list.AbstractListProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractListProcessor.java:414)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was an inappropriate installation of the NiFi service which did not have user login information which had appropriate access to the server it was trying to access.  It has been resolved now